# get particular string part in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript string like "firstHalf_0_0_0" or secondHalf_0_0_0". Now I want to get the string before the string "Half" from above both strings using javascript.Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var myString = "firstHalf_0_0_0";
var parts = myString.split("Half");
var thePart = parts[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'firstHalf_0_0_0',
    part = str.match(/(\w+)Half/)[1];

alert(part); // Alerts "first"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "firstHalf.....";
var index = str.indexOf("Half");
var substring = str.substr(0, index);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JAPy/) demo.

Answer (score 2):

Using this you can get any particular part of string.

```
var str= 'your string';
var result = str.split('_')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example here for your particular case.

http://jsfiddle.net/7kypu/3/

cheers!